# Service Reference Generates Incorrect Method Signature

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, asmx

We have an asmx web service project. When I add it to the project using the `Add Service Reference` option everything works fine. However, when my colleague does the same, he gets the wrong signature for the methods defined in the operation contract.

By wrong signature I mean the original methods receive entities as parameters which are generated in my colleague's project as `DataSet` parameters (The service reference structures are also different as shown in pictures. My colleague has more stuff). We are using VS 2013.

What's going on ?

[image]

[image: My Service Reference]

**EDIT:**

Service Contract

```
  [ServiceContract]
    public interface INetTransTntIntegration
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string CreateGlbTrns1LineCard(GlbTrns1LineCardEntity ent);

        [OperationContract]
        void CreateGlbTrns1LineCardTest();
    }
```

Generated Code (Colleague's incorrect code)

```
namespace TNT.ServiceReference {
using System.Data;


[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="ServiceReference.INetTransTntIntegration")]
public interface INetTransTntIntegration {

    // CODEGEN: Parameter 'CreateGlbTrns1LineCardResult' requires additional schema information that cannot be captured using the parameter mode. The specific attribute is 'System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute'.
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/INetTransTntIntegration/CreateGlbTrns1LineCard", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/INetTransTntIntegration/CreateGlbTrns1LineCardResponse")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
    TNT.ServiceReference.CreateGlbTrns1LineCardResponse CreateGlbTrns1LineCard(TNT.ServiceReference.CreateGlbTrns1LineCardRequest request);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/INetTransTntIntegration/CreateGlbTrns1LineCard", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/INetTransTntIntegration/CreateGlbTrns1LineCardResponse")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TNT.ServiceReference.CreateGlbTrns1LineCardResponse> CreateGlbTrns1LineCardAsync(TNT.ServiceReference.CreateGlbTrns1LineCardRequest request);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/INetTransTntIntegration/CreateGlbTrns1LineCardTest", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/INetTransTntIntegration/CreateGlbTrns1LineCardTestResponse")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
    void CreateGlbTrns1LineCardTest();

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/INetTransTntIntegration/CreateGlbTrns1LineCardTest", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/INetTransTntIntegration/CreateGlbTrns1LineCardTestResponse")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task CreateGlbTrns1LineCardTestAsync();
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="CreateGlbTrns1LineCard", WrapperNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class CreateGlbTrns1LineCardRequest {

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/", Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public System.Data.DataSet ent;

    public CreateGlbTrns1LineCardRequest() {
    }

    public CreateGlbTrns1LineCardRequest(System.Data.DataSet ent) {
        this.ent = ent;
    }
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="CreateGlbTrns1LineCardResponse", WrapperNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class CreateGlbTrns1LineCardResponse {

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/", Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string CreateGlbTrns1LineCardResult;

    public CreateGlbTrns1LineCardResponse() {
    }

    public CreateGlbTrns1LineCardResponse(string CreateGlbTrns1LineCardResult) {
        this.CreateGlbTrns1LineCardResult = CreateGlbTrns1LineCardResult;
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public interface INetTransTntIntegrationChannel : TNT.ServiceReference.INetTransTntIntegration, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel {
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class NetTransTntIntegrationClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TNT.ServiceReference.INetTransTntIntegration>, TNT.ServiceReference.INetTransTntIntegration {

    public NetTransTntIntegrationClient() {
    }

    public NetTransTntIntegrationClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName) {
    }

    public NetTransTntIntegrationClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public NetTransTntIntegrationClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public NetTransTntIntegrationClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress) {
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    TNT.ServiceReference.CreateGlbTrns1LineCardResponse TNT.ServiceReference.INetTransTntIntegration.CreateGlbTrns1LineCard(TNT.ServiceReference.CreateGlbTrns1LineCardRequest request) {
        return base.Channel.CreateGlbTrns1LineCard(request);
    }

    public string CreateGlbTrns1LineCard(System.Data.DataSet ent) {
        TNT.ServiceReference.CreateGlbTrns1LineCardRequest inValue = new TNT.ServiceReference.CreateGlbTrns1LineCardRequest();
        inValue.ent = ent;
        TNT.ServiceReference.CreateGlbTrns1LineCardResponse retVal = ((TNT.ServiceReference.INetTransTntIntegration)(this)).CreateGlbTrns1LineCard(inValue);
        return retVal.CreateGlbTrns1LineCardResult;
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TNT.ServiceReference.CreateGlbTrns1LineCardResponse> TNT.ServiceReference.INetTransTntIntegration.CreateGlbTrns1LineCardAsync(TNT.ServiceReference.CreateGlbTrns1LineCardRequest request) {
        return base.Channel.CreateGlbTrns1LineCardAsync(request);
    }

    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TNT.ServiceReference.CreateGlbTrns1LineCardResponse> CreateGlbTrns1LineCardAsync(System.Data.DataSet ent) {
        TNT.ServiceReference.CreateGlbTrns1LineCardRequest inValue = new TNT.ServiceReference.CreateGlbTrns1LineCardRequest();
        inValue.ent = ent;
        return ((TNT.ServiceReference.INetTransTntIntegration)(this)).CreateGlbTrns1LineCardAsync(inValue);
    }

    public void CreateGlbTrns1LineCardTest() {
        base.Channel.CreateGlbTrns1LineCardTest();
    }

    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task CreateGlbTrns1LineCardTestAsync() {
        return base.Channel.CreateGlbTrns1LineCardTestAsync();
    }
}
```

---

**My correctly generated code**

```
namespace TNT.NettransSvc {


    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="NettransSvc.INetTransTntIntegration")]
    public interface INetTransTntIntegration {

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/INetTransTntIntegration/CreateGlbTrns1LineCard", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/INetTransTntIntegration/CreateGlbTrns1LineCardResponse")]
        string CreateGlbTrns1LineCard(LLMTESTADAPTER.EntityClasses.GlbTrns1LineCardEntity ent);

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/INetTransTntIntegration/CreateGlbTrns1LineCard", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/INetTransTntIntegration/CreateGlbTrns1LineCardResponse")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> CreateGlbTrns1LineCardAsync(LLMTESTADAPTER.EntityClasses.GlbTrns1LineCardEntity ent);

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/INetTransTntIntegration/CreateGlbTrns1LineCardTest", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/INetTransTntIntegration/CreateGlbTrns1LineCardTestResponse")]
        void CreateGlbTrns1LineCardTest();

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/INetTransTntIntegration/CreateGlbTrns1LineCardTest", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/INetTransTntIntegration/CreateGlbTrns1LineCardTestResponse")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task CreateGlbTrns1LineCardTestAsync();
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public interface INetTransTntIntegrationChannel : TNT.NettransSvc.INetTransTntIntegration, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel {
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public partial class NetTransTntIntegrationClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TNT.NettransSvc.INetTransTntIntegration>, TNT.NettransSvc.INetTransTntIntegration {

        public NetTransTntIntegrationClient() {
        }

        public NetTransTntIntegrationClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName) {
        }

        public NetTransTntIntegrationClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public NetTransTntIntegrationClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public NetTransTntIntegrationClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(binding, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public string CreateGlbTrns1LineCard(LLMTESTADAPTER.EntityClasses.GlbTrns1LineCardEntity ent) {
            return base.Channel.CreateGlbTrns1LineCard(ent);
        }

        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> CreateGlbTrns1LineCardAsync(LLMTESTADAPTER.EntityClasses.GlbTrns1LineCardEntity ent) {
            return base.Channel.CreateGlbTrns1LineCardAsync(ent);
        }

        public void CreateGlbTrns1LineCardTest() {
            base.Channel.CreateGlbTrns1LineCardTest();
        }

        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task CreateGlbTrns1LineCardTestAsync() {
            return base.Channel.CreateGlbTrns1LineCardTestAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post code, not pictures. The key points have to be googlable.

Comment: @HenkHolterman The only visible difference seems to be the one in picture I don't have any clues otherwise. Any specific part of the code you want to see ?

Comment: A sample of the generated methods and the entity class.

Comment: But its probably a setting in the import dialog.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I added the generated reference and service contract. Unfortunately the ORM in the project is LLBLGEN and they are dlls so I am not able to post the entity code definition. I verified that The import dialog is the same in both scenarios

Comment: @HenkHolterman I also posted the correctly generated version. Seems like his version is dependent on some kind of Request/Response Pattern

Comment: Do both projects reference the same assemblies? Especially the one with GlbTrns1LineCardEntity ? Also compare the settings under the Advanced button.

Comment: @henkholterman yes both are same

Comment: Check again, something must be different. Check the basics, don't assume anything. The incorrect version doesn't seem to know about the entity type.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Finally got it. My colleagues visual studio weren't converting the entities automatically for some reason so I had to explicitly set the reuse option for those. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Just as a side-note: One does simply not use ASMX anymore

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair you are right but the project is so old that we just had to in order to carry on :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague's visual studio weren't converting the entities automatically for some reason so I had to explicitly set the reuse option for those dlls (containing entity definitions/operations) in order for entities to be identified.

In my case I did not have to check any of these but it was working fine.

I would like to thank @HenkHolterman for his time.

[image]